# Check whether a String is not Null and not Empty

Tags: java, string, conditional-statements, string-comparison, boolean-logic

How can I check whether a string is not `null` and not empty?

```
public void doStuff(String str)
{
    if (str != null && str != "**here I want to check the 'str' is empty or not**")
    {
        /* handle empty string */
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: You should probably use `PreparedStatement` and such instead of constructing an SQL query by string concatenation primitives. Avoids all kinds of injection vulnerabilities, much more readable, etc.

Comment: You can create class that will check for null values or null object.
That will help you improving reuse-ability..
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16833309/1490962

Comment: This condition can be expressed as a *java.util.function.Predicate* in the following way `Predicate.<String>isEqual(null).or(String::isEmpty).negate()` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74649555/17949945).

Answer (score 998, accepted):

What about [isEmpty()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) ?

```
if(str != null && !str.isEmpty())
```

Be sure to use the parts of `&&` in this order, because java will not proceed to evaluate the second part if the first part of `&&` fails, thus ensuring you will not get a null pointer exception from `str.isEmpty()` if `str` is null.

Beware, it's only available since Java SE 1.6. You have to check `str.length() == 0` on previous versions.

---

To ignore whitespace as well:

```
if(str != null && !str.trim().isEmpty())
```

(since Java 11 `str.trim().isEmpty()` can be reduced to `str.isBlank()` which will also test for other Unicode white spaces)

Wrapped in a handy function:

```
public static boolean empty( final String s ) {
  // Null-safe, short-circuit evaluation.
  return s == null || s.trim().isEmpty();
}
```

Becomes:

```
if( !empty( str ) )
```

Comment: Note that `isEmpty()` appears to require a String instance (non-static). Invoking this on a null reference will throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: Or if(str != null && !str.trim().isEmpty()), to ignore whitespace.

Comment: if((txt.getText().length()) == 0 ) // get element from layout

Comment: I'd recommend to use `TextUtils.isEmpty(String)` to check is string empty or null. Nice and short. The TextUtils class is a part of Android SDK.

Comment: boolean check = (yourstring != null)  ?    (yourstring.length() > 0 ? true : false) : false;

Comment: @user1154390: sometimes its worth explicitly using true and false for clarity, but when condition returns true for true and false for false, its unnecessary complexity. Simply say `(str != null && str.length() > 0)`.

Comment: Need to use a simple Predicate to be on safe side.    Predicate<String> isBlank = str -> str != null && str.isBlank();

Answer (score 247):

## Use [org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

I like to use Apache [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) for these kinds of things, and especially the [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) utility class:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(str)) {
    ...
} 

if (StringUtils.isBlank(str)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: isn't Apache commons-lang an overkill if you can just use isEmpty? Just curious.

Comment: @zengr - no, because you most certainly would use other things as well :)

Comment: @zengr Indeed, if you only use `isEmpty` or `isBlank`, maybe it is not usefull to include a third-party library. You can simply create your own utility class to provide such method. However, as Bozho explain, the `commons-lang` project provide many usefull methods!

Comment: Because `StringUtils.isNotBlank(str)` does the null-checking as well.

Comment: If you use Spring Framework, this could be ALREADY bundled in the jars of the framework.

Comment: If your app is already using this Apache Commons then its fine. Note there is Apache Commons lang3 `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isNotBlank`

Answer (score 106):

Just adding Android in here:

```
import android.text.TextUtils;

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
...
}
```

Comment: @staticx, The StringUtils method changed in Lang version 2.0.  It no longer trims the CharSequence.  That functionality is available in isBlank().

Answer (score 52):

To add to @BJorn and @SeanPatrickFloyd The Guava way to do this is:

```
Strings.nullToEmpty(str).isEmpty(); 
// or
Strings.isNullOrEmpty(str);
```

Commons Lang is more readable at times but I have been slowly relying more on Guava plus sometimes Commons Lang is confusing when it comes to `isBlank()` (as in what is whitespace or not).

Guava's version of Commons Lang `isBlank` would be:

```
Strings.nullToEmpty(str).trim().isEmpty()
```

I will say code that doesn't allow `""` (empty) **AND** `null` is suspicious and potentially buggy in that it probably doesn't handle all cases where is not allowing `null` makes sense (although for SQL I can understand as SQL/HQL is weird about `''`).

Comment: second Guava too. Guava follows a convention of plural static classes. For String, try Strings for static methods like isNullOrEmpty(str).

Answer (score 35):

```
str != null && str.length() != 0
```

alternatively

```
str != null && !str.equals("")
```

or

```
str != null && !"".equals(str)
```

Note: The second check (first and second alternatives) assumes str is not null. It's ok only because the first check is doing that (and Java doesn't does the second check if the first is false)!

IMPORTANT: DON'T use == for string equality. == checks the pointer is equal, not the value. Two strings can be in different memory addresses (two instances) but have the same value!

Comment: thanks...the str.length() worked for me. My case was that i'm getting the values from the array after querying from the database. Even if the data was empty, when i did the str.length it was giving "1" length. Very strange but thanks for showing me this.

Comment: That has to do with the internals of the database. Either it's a char field instead of a varchar field (so it pads with spaces) or the database doesn't like empty strings. I guess the best is to preprocess those values after/while querying (in the data access later of the app).

Comment: I think checking the length is better than 'equals' because it's an O(1) operation since the length is cached in case of String.

Answer (score 30):

Almost every library I know defines a utility class called `StringUtils`, `StringUtil` or `StringHelper`, and they usually include the method you are looking for.

<s>My personal favorite is [Apache Commons / Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/), where in the [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class, you get both the</s>

1. [StringUtils.isEmpty(String)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) and the
2. [StringUtils.isBlank(String)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29) method

(The first checks whether a string is null or empty, the second checks whether it is null, empty or whitespace only)

There are similar utility classes in Spring, Wicket and lots of other libs. If you don't use external libraries, you might want to introduce a StringUtils class in your own project.

---

Update: many years have passed, and these days I'd recommend using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Strings.isNullOrEmpty(string)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty-java.lang.String-) method.

Comment: I would like to ask why you recommend now this? I would like to know if there is a 
 difference between the Strings.isNullOrEmpty(string) and  StringUtils.isEmpty(String)

Comment: @vicangel Apache Commons methods are full of assumptions and things I didn't ask for. With Guava, I get exactly what I asked for and nothing more or less

Answer (score 25):

This works for me:

```
import com.google.common.base.Strings;

if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(myString)) {
       return myString;
}
```

> Returns true if the given string is null or is the empty string.
>
> Consider normalizing your string references with nullToEmpty. If you
>   do, you can use String.isEmpty() instead of this method, and you won't
>   need special null-safe forms of methods like String.toUpperCase
>   either. Or, if you'd like to normalize "in the other direction,"
>   converting empty strings to null, you can use emptyToNull.

Comment: <dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
 <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
 <version>12.0</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 17):

There is a new method in [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11): `String#isBlank`

> Returns true if the string is empty or contains only white space codepoints, otherwise false.

```
jshell> "".isBlank()
$7 ==> true

jshell> " ".isBlank()
$8 ==> true

jshell> " ! ".isBlank()
$9 ==> false
```

This could be combined with `Optional` to check if string is null or empty

```
boolean isNullOrEmpty = Optional.ofNullable(str).map(String::isBlank).orElse(true);
```

[String#isBlank](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank())

Answer (score 11):

For completeness: If you are **already using the Spring framework**, the **[StringUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html)** provide the **method**

```
org.springframework.util.StringUtils.hasLength(String str)
```

> Returns:
>   true if the String is not null and has length

**as well as the method**

```
org.springframework.util.StringUtils.hasText(String str)
```

> Returns:
>   true if the String is not null, its length is greater than 0, and it does not contain whitespace only

Comment: we can use StringUtils.isEmpty(param) method.

Answer (score 10):

How about:

```
if(str!= null && str.length() != 0 )
```

Comment: throws NullPointerException if str is NULL.

Comment: @Mindwin That's not true. It will not execute the code to the right of the `&&` if str == null, thus preventing a NullPointerException. (Source: I just tried)

Comment: I stand corrected. Won't delete the comment out of shame so Zach and GI Joe won't be left with responses hanging out of nowhere. Lolz. BUT its nice to know that, this skipping might cause logical failures if you do something else other than just test stuff and return a boolean on the skipped method calls.

Comment: @Mindwin It's nice to know how the language you are using actually works. If you don't understand short-circuit evaluation, either don't use it or, better still, learn about it.

Answer (score 8):

Returns true or false based on input

```
Predicate<String> p = (s)-> ( s != null && !s.isEmpty());
p.test(string);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use Apache StringUtils' isNotBlank method like

```
StringUtils.isNotBlank(str)
```

It will return true only if the str is not null and is not empty.

Comment: actually if str is null here, the statement returns true

Comment: Thats true , my bad !!
Instead using apache-commons' StringUtils.isNotEmpty(str) would do the job.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isNotBlank()` or `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isNotEmpty`. The decision between these two is based on what you actually want to check for.

The [isNotBlank()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank(java.lang.CharSequence)) checks that the input parameter is:

- not Null,
- not the empty string ("")
- not a sequence of whitespace characters ("    ")

The [isNotEmpty()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) checks only that the input parameter is

- not null
- not the Empty String ("")

Answer (score 7):

You can use the functional style of checking:

```
Optional.ofNullable(str)
    .filter(s -> !(s.trim().isEmpty()))
    .ifPresent(result -> {
       // your query setup goes here
    });
```

Comment: I would recommend using a map for the trim e.g:

  Optional.ofNullable(str)
      .map(String::trim)
      .filter(String::isEmpty)
      .ifPresent(this::setStringMethod);

Comment: but
.filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to include the whole library; just include the code you want from it.  You'll have to maintain it yourself; but it's a pretty straight forward function.  Here it is copied from [commons.apache.org](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#line.216)

```
    /**
 * <p>Checks if a String is whitespace, empty ("") or null.</p>
 *
 * <pre>
 * StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true
 * StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true
 * StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true
 * StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false
 * StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param str  the String to check, may be null
 * @return <code>true</code> if the String is null, empty or whitespace
 * @since 2.0
 */
public static boolean isBlank(String str) {
    int strLen;
    if (str == null || (strLen = str.length()) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
        if ((Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)) == false)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

test equals with an empty string and null in the same conditional:

```
if(!"".equals(str) && str != null) {
    // do stuff.
}
```

Does not throws `NullPointerException` if str is null, since [`Object.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) returns false if arg is `null`.

the other construct `str.equals("")` would throw the dreaded `NullPointerException`. Some might consider bad form using a String literal as the object upon wich `equals()` is called but it does the job.

Also check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/531825/1532705

Comment: so why add never reached code `str != null`. `!"".equals(str)` already do the job

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution :

```
private boolean stringNotEmptyOrNull(String st) {
    return st != null && !st.isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As seanizer said above, Apache StringUtils is fantastic for this, if you were to include guava you should do the following;

```
public List<Employee> findEmployees(String str, int dep) {
 Preconditions.checkState(StringUtils.isNotBlank(str), "Invalid input, input is blank or null");
 /** code here **/
}
```

May I also recommend that you refer to the columns in your result set by name rather than by index, this will make your code much easier to maintain.

Comment: No need to use apache commons from guava though, there is a Strings class in guava too: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html

Comment: I added some Guava examples for novice Java users that land on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13146903/318174 .

Answer (score 2):

I've made my own utility function to check several strings at once, rather than having an if statement full of `if(str != null && !str.isEmpty && str2 != null && !str2.isEmpty)`. This is the function:

```
public class StringUtils{

    public static boolean areSet(String... strings)
    {
        for(String s : strings)
            if(s == null || s.isEmpty)
                return false;

        return true;
    }   

}
```

so I can simply write:

```
if(!StringUtils.areSet(firstName,lastName,address)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Would be nicer to use the signature: `areSet(String... strings)` can then be invoked without the array creation: `if(!StringUtils.areSet(firstName, lastName, address))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use StringUtils.isEmpty(), It will result true if the string is either null or empty.

```
 String str1 = "";
 String str2 = null;

 if(StringUtils.isEmpty(str)){
     System.out.println("str1 is null or empty");
 }

 if(StringUtils.isEmpty(str2)){
     System.out.println("str2 is null or empty");
 }
```

will result in

str1 is null or empty

str2 is null or empty

Comment: Or just use `isNotBlank`

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using Java 8 and want to have a more Functional Programming approach, you can define a `Function` that manages the control and then you can reuse it and `apply()` whenever is needed.

Coming to practice, you can define the `Function` as

```
Function<String, Boolean> isNotEmpty = s -> s != null && !"".equals(s)
```

Then, you can use it by simply calling the `apply()` method as:

```
String emptyString = "";
isNotEmpty.apply(emptyString); // this will return false

String notEmptyString = "StackOverflow";
isNotEmpty.apply(notEmptyString); // this will return true
```

If you prefer, you can define a `Function` that checks if the `String` is empty and then negate it with `!`.

In this case, the `Function` will look like as :

```
Function<String, Boolean> isEmpty = s -> s == null || "".equals(s)
```

Then, you can use it by simply calling the `apply()` method as:

```
String emptyString = "";
!isEmpty.apply(emptyString); // this will return false

String notEmptyString = "StackOverflow";
!isEmpty.apply(notEmptyString); // this will return true
```

Comment: This is how I like to do it, when I'm worried about performance cost or side-effects, and no imports readily to hand.

Answer (score 2):

With [Java 8 Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) you can do:

```
public Boolean isStringCorrect(String str) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(str)
            .map(String::trim)
            .map(string -> !str.isEmpty())
            .orElse(false);
}
```

In this expression, you will handle `String`s that consist of spaces as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring Boot then below code will do the Job

```
StringUtils.hasLength(str)
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if a string is not empty you can check if it is `null` but this doesn't account for a string with whitespace. You could use `str.trim()` to trim all the whitespace and then chain `.isEmpty()` to ensure that the result is not empty.

```java
if(str != null && !str.trim().isEmpty()) { /* do your stuffs here */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise Guava or Apache Commons according to your actual need. Check the different behaviors in my example code:

```
import com.google.common.base.Strings;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

/**
 * Created by hu0983 on 2016.01.13..
 */
public class StringNotEmptyTesting {
  public static void main(String[] args){
        String a = "  ";
        String b = "";
        String c=null;

    System.out.println("Apache:");
    if(!StringUtils.isNotBlank(a)){
        System.out.println(" a is blank");
    }
    if(!StringUtils.isNotBlank(b)){
        System.out.println(" b is blank");
    }
    if(!StringUtils.isNotBlank(c)){
        System.out.println(" c is blank");
    }
    System.out.println("Google:");

    if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(Strings.emptyToNull(a))){
        System.out.println(" a is NullOrEmpty");
    }
    if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(b)){
        System.out.println(" b is NullOrEmpty");
    }
    if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(c)){
        System.out.println(" c is NullOrEmpty");
    }
  }
}
```

Result:
Apache:
 a is blank
 b is blank
 c is blank
Google:
 b is NullOrEmpty
 c is NullOrEmpty

Answer (score 1):

Simply, to ignore white space as well:

```
if (str == null || str.trim().length() == 0) {
    // str is empty
} else {
    // str is not empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the below example, I have added 4 test cases in main method. three test cases will pass when you follow above commented snipts.

```
public class EmptyNullBlankWithNull {
    public static boolean nullEmptyBlankWithNull(String passedStr) {
        if (passedStr != null && !passedStr.trim().isEmpty() && !passedStr.trim().equals("null")) {
            // TODO when string is null , Empty, Blank
            return true;
        }else{
            // TODO when string is null , Empty, Blank
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stringNull = null; // test case 1
        String stringEmpty = ""; // test case 2
        String stringWhiteSpace = "  "; // test case 3
        String stringWhiteSpaceWithNull = " null"; // test case 4
        System.out.println("TestCase result:------ "+nullEmptyBlankWithNull(stringWhiteSpaceWithNull));
        
    }
}
```

BUT test case 4 will return true(it has white space before null) which is wrong:

```
String stringWhiteSpaceWithNull = " null"; // test case 4
```

We have to add below conditions to make it work propper:

```
!passedStr.trim().equals("null")
```

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

[`java.util.function.Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html) is a *Functional interface* representing a *boolean-valued Function*.

`Predicate` offers several `static` and `default` methods which allow to perform logical operations `AND` **&&**, `OR` **||**, `NOT` **!** and chain conditions in a fluent way.

Logical condition *"not empty && not null"* can be expressed in the following way:

```java
Predicate.not(Predicate.<String>isEqual(null).or(String::isEmpty));
```

Or, alternatively:

```java
Predicate.<String>isEqual(null).or(String::isEmpty).negate();
```

Or:

```java
Predicate.<String>isEqual(null).or(""::equals).negate();
```

## [`Predicate.equal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#isEqual(java.lang.Object)) is your friend

Static method `Predicate.isEqual()` expects a reference to the target object for equality comparison (*an empty string in this case*). This comparison is **not hostile** to `null`, which means `isEqual()` performs a *null-check* internally as well as utility method `Objects.equals(Object, Object)`, so that comparison of `null` and `null` would return `true` without raising an exception.

A quote from the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#isEqual(java.lang.Object)):

> **Returns:**
>
> a predicate that tests if two arguments are equal according to
> `Objects.equals(Object, Object)`

The predicate the compares the given element against the `null` can be written as:

```java
Predicate.isEqual(null)
```

## [`Predicate.or()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#or(java.util.function.Predicate)) OR ||

Default method `Predicate.or()` allows chaining the conditions relationship among which can be expressed through logical `OR` **||**.

That's how we can combine the two conditions: *empty **||** null*

```java
Predicate.isEqual(null).or(String::isEmpty)
```

Now we need to negate this predicate

## [`Predicate.not()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)) & [`Predicate.negete()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#negate())

To perform the logical negation, we have two options: `static` method `not()` and `default` method `negate()`.

Here's how resulting predicates might be written:

```java
public static final Predicate<String> NON_EMPTY_NON_NULL =
    Predicate.<String>isEqual(null).or(String::isEmpty).negate();
```

***Note** that in this case the type of the predicate* `Predicate.isEqual(null)` *would be inferred as* `Predicate<Object>` *since* `null` *gives no clue to the compiler what should be the type of the argument, and we can resolve this issue using a so-called Type-witness* `<String>isEqual()`.

Or, alternatively

```java
public static final Predicate<String> NON_EMPTY_NON_NULL =
    Predicate.not(Predicate.<String>isEqual(null).or(String::isEmpty));
```

***Note:** `String::isEmpty` *can be also written as* `""::equals`, *and if you need to check whether the string is Blank (contains various forms of unprintable characters or empty) you can use method reference* `String::isBlank`. *And if you need to verify a few more conditions, you can add as many as you need by chaining them via* `or()` *and* `and()` *methods.*

## Usage Example

`Predicate` is used an argument of such method as `Stream.filter()`, `Collection.removeIf()`, `Collectors.partitioningBy()`, etc. and you can create your custom ones.

Consider the following example:

```java
List<String> strings = Stream.of("foo", "bar", "", null, "baz")
    .filter(NON_EMPTY_NON_NULL)
    .map("* "::concat) // append a prefix to make sure that empty string can't sneak in
    .toList();
        
strings.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
* foo
* bar
* baz
```

Comment: `public static final Predicate<String> NON_EMPTY_NON_NULL =
    Predicate.not(Predicate.isEqual(null).or(String::isEmpty));` returns "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: apparently, you can fix the above by adding `<String>.isEqual` like this `public static final Predicate<String> NON_EMPTY_NON_NULL = Predicate.not(Predicate.<String>isEqual(null).or(String::isEmpty));`

Comment: @mellow-yellow You're right, without a type-witness the type of `Predicate.isEqual(null)` would be inferred by the compiler as `Predicate<? extends Object>`, hence we need to provide the type explicitly. Amended.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring framework then you can use method:

```
org.springframework.util.StringUtils.isEmpty(@Nullable Object str);
```

This method accepts any Object as an argument, comparing it to null and the empty String. As a consequence, this method will never return true for a non-null non-String object.

Comment: Note that the documentation for `StringUtils` explicitly states "Mainly for internal use within the framework; consider Apache's Commons Lang for a more comprehensive suite of String utilities."

Answer (score 0):

To check on if all the string attributes in an object is empty(Instead of using !=null on all the field names following java reflection api approach

```
private String name1;
private String name2;
private String name3;

public boolean isEmpty()  {

    for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        try {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(this) != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred in processing");
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This method would return true if all the String field values are blank,It would return false if any one values is present in the String attributes

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a situation where I must check that "null" (as a string) must be regarded as empty. Also white space and an actual ***null*** must return true.
I've finally settled on the following function...

```
public boolean isEmpty(String testString) {
  return ((null==testString) || "".equals((""+testString).trim()) || "null".equals((""+testString).toLowerCase()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to validate your method parameters you can use follow simple method

```
public class StringUtils {

    static boolean anyEmptyString(String ... strings) {
        return Stream.of(strings).anyMatch(s -> s == null || s.isEmpty());
    }

}
```

Example:

```
public String concatenate(String firstName, String lastName) {
    if(StringUtils.anyBlankString(firstName, lastName)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty field found");
    }
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone using springboot, then the following option might be helpful,

```
import static org.springframework.util.StringUtils.hasLength;
```

```java
if (hasLength(str)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The better way to handle null in the string is,

```
str!=null && !str.equalsIgnoreCase("null") && !str.isEmpty()
```

In short,

```
str.length()>0 && !str.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import android.text.TextUtils;

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str)||!str.equalsIgnoreCase("") {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Adding a few words of explanation is better than just some code. For example, why did you import a library?