# test if fields is null and prevent user from saving to sqlite - android

Tags: android, sqlite

how do i test if the field isn't filled up by the user? i want to show a prompt that they have to fill up the fields completely. but this code still accepts even if the name is null and the number is entered.

```
public void onClick(View arg0)
{
    switch(arg0.getId())
    {
    case R.id.bSQLUpdate:
        boolean diditwork = true;
        try
        {
        String name = sqlName.getText().toString();
        String number = sqlNumber.getText().toString();

        GroupDb entry = new GroupDb(ContactDb.this);
        entry.open();
        if(name != null && number != null)
        {
            if((!entry.hasDuplicateNameNumber(name, number)) )
            {
                entry.createEntry(name, number);

            }
            else
            {
                diditwork = false;
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Error");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Duplicate name or number. Please try again.");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
                sqlName.setText("");
                sqlNumber.setText("");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            diditwork = false;
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Error");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("Please fill up all fields. Please try again.");
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
            sqlName.setText("");
            sqlNumber.setText("");
        }

        entry.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            diditwork = false;
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Update failed");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
            sqlName.setText("");
            sqlNumber.setText("");
        }
        finally
        {
            if(diditwork)
            {
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Contact list updated");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Success");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
                sqlName.setText("");
                sqlNumber.setText("");
            }
        }
        break;

    case R.id.bSQLOpenView:
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(ContactDb.this, CustomListView.class);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        break;

    }

}// end onclick
```

Comment: Use `trim()` and `length()` method - `if(name.trim().length()!=0 && number.trim().length()!=0) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tested your string with null.When text box is empty String name is not null, it is an empty string.So compare it like below

```
if(!name.trim().equals("") && !number.trim().equals("")){
 }
```

Comment: it still saves the input if i only entered a number and an empty string in name

Comment: You can try by trimming the string.

Comment: my bad. it worked just right. i just uninstalled the app and reinstalled it again. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try checking the following condition

```
if((name.length() > 0) && (number .length() > 0))
        {
// do the work

}
```

instead of

```
if(name != null && number != null)
        {
// do the work
}
```

Comment: `length()` is an instance method of `String`.

Comment: oh, it worked. thanks. i thought it will count the spaces as length() so i never used it. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the answers above, I recently found this library to create something to test user input a little more robustly.

https://github.com/throrin19/Android-Validator

> Form Validator Library for Android is based on Zend_Validator coded in
>   PHP. This library is intended to simplify and streamline the code to
>   validate a form Android. For the moment, the form can just handle the
>   EditText. Other elements will emerge in future versions.

As the previous answers have suggested you can check the length or see if the string is blank. There is already a comprehensive SO previous question on this for Java so it is relevant to you here in Android. Well worth a look 
[Java, check whether a string is not null and not empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598770/how-to-check-whether-a-string-is-not-null-empty)