# Empty String Validation

Tags: java, null, string

I've read through this SO thread: [Java, check whether a string is not null and not empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598770/how-to-check-whether-a-string-is-not-null-empty)

The question that arises (and was not answered in that thread), is:

`Why is string.isEmpty() better than using string.equals("") ?` In the same answer the poster states that prior to J6, people would use `string.length == 0` as a way to check for empty strings. Am I missing something, because they all seem to do exactly the same thing... making it just a matter of *beautifying* your code.

Comment: just beautifying your code...  look at the source, `isEmpty()` uses `string.length == 0`...

Comment: Probably speed of execution. The problem is that each new browser version makes this or that feature take less of more time to execute so the conversation gets a different answer depending on "when" it happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is string.isEmpty() better than using string.equals("") ?

Just look at the source of [`String#isEmpty()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.isEmpty%28%29):

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return count == 0;
}
```

It simply returns the result of comparing `count` variable stored as a part of the class with `0`. No heavy computation. The value is already there.

Whereas, the `String.equals()` method does lot of computations, viz, *typecasting*, *reference comparison*, *length comparison* - [`String#equals(Object)` source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29). So, to avoid those runtime operations, you can simply use `isEmpty()` to check for empty strings.
That would be a slower by a minute difference though.

---

*Note:* The ***Oracle*** Java 7 version of `String.isEmpty()` uses `value.length == 0`, as it [no more stores](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/) the `count` and `offset` variable. In ***openjdk-7*** though, it still uses the `count` variable there.

But still, the `value.length` computation will be a bit faster than all those operations in `equals()` method.
Apart from the performance difference, which is really not of much concern, and the difference if any would be minute, the `String.isEmpty()` method seems more clear about your intents. So, I prefer to use that method for checking for empty strings.

And at last, of course, *don't believe* on what you see. Just benchmark your code using both the methods, and see for any measurable differences if any.

Comment: Careful, that's java 6-. Java 7 uses `value.length == 0` as there is no more sharing of `char[]`.

Comment: so basically `isEmpty()` is faster if you have a significant number of checks to process, otherwise the performance hit is unlikely to make anyone cry... right?

Comment: @RohitJain Which version of java are you looking at?

Comment: @SnakeDoc. Yeah, if only the number of comparison is too much, is it going to affect. That is also not by much difference.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. Java 7. - [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java?av=f)

Comment: @RohitJain I see that. The openjdk must be different than Oracle's then. String no longer has `offset` and `count`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. Oh! I'll also check onto the Oracle's one, when I switch on my Windows PC.

Answer (score 6):

The best to use is

```
"".equals(yourString)
```

as this avoids the null pointer exception.

If you use

```
string.equals("")
```

and if your string is null, it will throw a null pointer exception.

and again the problem with `isEmpty` is that

> It Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0

So if your string is empty it will also cause NPE.

Comment: I agree this is better, though unfortunately it's less pretty (and not quite as clear).

Comment: There is something to be said for self-documenting code.  I'm not sure I agree @snakedoc .

Comment: "So if your string is empty it will also cause NPE." -- If your string is empty, isEmpty() will return true. If your *reference* of String type is null, attempting to call isEmpty() will throw a NPE, as would attempting to call any other method.

Comment: if i'm also checking for `null` in the same `if` statement, then the NPE shouldn't matter... ie: `if (string == null || string.isEmpty()) { ... };`

Answer (score 3):

The call of `isEmpty()` expresses your intentions better, thus improving readability. Readers spend less time understanding what is your intention behind the check: rather than thinking that you are interested in checking string's equality or determining its length, they see that all you want to know is if the string is empty or not.

There is no performance difference, as `isEmpty()` is implemented by checking the length.

Answer (score 1):

as Lucas stated, one's not better than the other...isEmpty is a little more readable, nothing more, nothing less.  There's no significant performance hit or anything like that using one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get one answer, everything is depending on the programming language and how to program your.

For Example in C#:

```
 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) 
    return "is null or empty";
```

Comment: Yea but this question is tagged *Java*.

Answer (score 0):

Use the util method provided by apache commons

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29

If you feel like you can even write your own isEmpty(String input) method

This approach has following advantages
  It makes your intentions clear
  You are safe in case of nulls.