# Best way to verify string is empty or null

Tags: java, regex, string, trim, is-empty

i am sure this must have been asked before in different ways - as isEmptyOrNull is so common yet people implement it differently. but i have below curious query in terms of best available approach which is good for memory and performance both.

1) Below does not account for all spaces like in case of empty XML tag

```
return inputString==null || inputString.length()==0;
```

2) Below one takes care but trim can eat some performance + memory

```
return inputString==null || inputString.trim().length()==0;
```

3) Combining one and two can save some performance + memory  (As Chris suggested in comments)

```
return inputString==null || inputString.trim().length()==0 || inputString.trim().length()==0;
```

4) Converted to pattern matcher (invoked only when string is non zero length)

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+");

return inputString==null || inputString.length()==0 || p.matcher(inputString).matches();
```

5) Using libraries like -
      Apache Commons (`StringUtils.isBlank/isEmpty`)
      or Spring (`StringUtils.isEmpty`) 
      or Guava (`Strings.isNullOrEmpty`) 
      or any other option?

Comment: inputString!=null && inputString.isEmpty(); more refined inputString!=null && inputString.trim().isEmpty();

Comment: You can also use Apache String utils [isEmpty()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) this does the null check as well as space checks.

Comment: `isEmpty` is "new" in java 6 and implementations that are older or want to stay java 5 compatible will have to use length check.

Comment: If you do `return inputString==null || inputString.length()==0 || inputString.trim().length()==0;` (combining 1 and 2) then trim is only invoked on non-zero-length string. You might add 3 to it too.,

Comment: @ChristianFries Yes, I agree - same approach can be used for both trim() and pattern matcher. But let me ask it this way - trim() or matcher()  which one is costlier?

Comment: Guava has Strings.isNullOrEmpty() which i am using the most at the moment!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether a string is not null and not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598770/check-whether-a-string-is-not-null-and-not-empty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't seen any fully-native solutions, so here's one:

```
return str == null || str.chars().allMatch(Character::isWhitespace);
```

Basically, use the native Character.isWhitespace() function. From there, you can achieve different levels of optimization, depending on how much it matters (I can assure you that in 99.99999% of use cases, no further optimization is necessary):

```
return str == null || str.length() == 0 || str.chars().allMatch(Character::isWhitespace);
```

Or, to be really optimal (but hecka ugly):

```
int len;
if (str == null || (len = str.length()) == 0) return true;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (!Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i))) return false;
}
return true;
```

One thing I like to do:

```
Optional<String> notBlank(String s) {
  return s == null || s.chars().allMatch(Character::isWhitepace))
    ? Optional.empty()
    : Optional.of(s);
}

...

notBlank(myStr).orElse("some default")
```

Answer (score 43):

Useful method from Apache Commons:

```
 org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isBlank(String str)
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.String)

Comment: Guava has Strings.isNullOrEmpty() which I am using quite often these days

Comment: isNullOrEmpty does not check the case when the input string consists of multiple whitespaces

Answer (score 25):

To detect if a string is null or empty, you can use the following without including any external dependencies on your project and still keeping your code simple/clean:

```
if(myString==null || myString.isEmpty()){
    //do something
}
```

or if blank spaces need to be detected as well:

```
if(myString==null || myString.trim().isEmpty()){
    //do something
}
```

you could easily wrap these into utility methods to be more concise since these are very common checks to make:

```
public final class StringUtils{

    private StringUtils() { }   

    public static bool isNullOrEmpty(string s){
        if(s==null || s.isEmpty()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool isNullOrWhiteSpace(string s){
        if(s==null || s.trim().isEmpty()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then call these methods via:

`if(StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(myString)){...}`

and

`if(StringUtils.isNullOrWhiteSpace(myString)){...}`

Comment: updated thanks. I inevitably make that mistake every time and then compile it, see the error, and realize ive made this mistake for the 9 billionth time :)

Comment: @zapl or statement in java is short-circuit. It will break if myString is null

Comment: @JamesWierzba answer was `if (s.isEmpty||s==null)` which does short circuit with a NPE in case of null :) removed comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: And it doesnt take care of blank spaces :)

Comment: The question only mentioned null or empty. If blank spaces need to be detected as well, then this can easily be changed to `if(myString==null || myString.trim().isEmpty()){...}`

Comment: String now has a .isBlank() method

Answer (score 15):

Just to show java 8's stance to remove null values.

```
String s = Optional.ofNullable(myString).orElse("");
if (s.trim().isEmpty()) {
    ...
}
```

Makes sense if you can use `Optional<String>`.

Comment: Thanks Joop, I think this one is also a clean solution - It will not work for multi-space blank strings like "   ".

Comment: @prash: added a trim for good order, but apache commons is unbeatable.  ;)

Comment: I have to say I think that the use of Optional is infecting the Java community like a bad disease. I have never before seen a feature that takes so much extra typing to achieve was is so simple yet adopted by so many sheeple at a time when competitive languages are going for more terse solutions. It must make non Java developers laugh at us. I haven't even mentioned the extra CPU and memory consumption when OptionalS are instantiated returned by methods that get called millions of times a second - but it's all running in the cloud so CPU and memory are almost free right?

Comment: @Volksman I agree that 1. some other languages have better (designed) constructs, 2. Optional is a late addition, an artifact with an unripe API. But it is 1. better than null, 2. allows some nice operations à la map.

Comment: @JoopEggen I've been using polymorphic "Null" classes/objects since C++ days to store items in template/generic collections that "represent" null but I've recently been working in large scale systems that already have performance issues (CPU + Memory) processing thousands of txns/second. If we change working code that returns null by wrapping each return value in an Optional we'll be allocating thousands more objects on the heap every second, making a struggling system do more work for no benefit (IMHO) and a lot of pain or increased infrastructure costs to cope. Conceptually awesome though!

Comment: @Volksman 100% true; also waves of small refactorings is productive (though one should refactor during development to keeep the code fine). Performance might surprise, but is indeed not optimal.

Answer (score 8):

This one from *Google Guava* could check out "null and empty String" in the same time.

```
Strings.isNullOrEmpty("Your string.");
```

Add a dependency with Maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

with Gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
}
```

Comment: Could you mention which library you are using the `Strings` class from?

Comment: From "Google Guava". I have edited the answer with library.

Comment: Guava dependency size: 2.3 MB for only checking if a string is null or empty... Guava have a lack of modularization.

Answer (score 4):

Apache Commons Lang has `StringUtils.isEmpty(String str)` method which returns true if argument is empty or null

Answer (score 4):

Using the **Spring Framework** library check whether the given String is empty:

```
f(ObjectUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
    //... The string is blank or null
}
```

Comment: As of Spring 5.3 `isEmpty` is deprecated. Instead, it's recommended to use following alternatives: `hasLength(String), hasText(String) or ObjectUtils.isEmpty(Object)`

Answer (score 2):

```
Optional.ofNullable(label)
.map(String::trim)
.map(string -> !label.isEmpty)
.orElse(false)
```

OR

`TextUtils.isNotBlank(label);`

the last solution will check if not null and trimm the str at the same time

Comment: TextUtils from apache httpcore.

Answer (score 1):

## Simply and clearly:

```
if (str == null || str.trim().length() == 0) {
    // str is empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In most of the cases, `StringUtils.isBlank(str)` from apache commons library would solve it. But if there is case, where input string being checked has null value within quotes, it fails to check such cases.

Take an example where I have an input object which was converted into string using `String.valueOf(obj)` API. In case obj reference is null, String.valueOf returns "null" instead of null.

When you attempt to use, `StringUtils.isBlank("null")`, API fails miserably, you may have to check for such use cases as well to make sure your validation is proper.

Answer (score 1):

With the openJDK 11 you can use the internal validation to check if the String is null or just white spaces

```
import jdk.internal.joptsimple.internal.Strings;
...

String targetString;
if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(tragetString)) {}
```

Comment: Nice, they stole this from C# I think. Missed it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Optional and Apache commons Stringutils library

```
Optional.ofNullable(StringUtils.noEmpty(string1)).orElse(string2);
```

here it will check if the **string1** is not null and not empty else it will return **string2**

Answer (score 0):

If you have to test more than one string in the same validation, you can do something like this:

```java
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class StringHelper {

  public static Boolean hasBlank(String ... strings) {

    Predicate<String> isBlank = s -> s == null || s.trim().isEmpty();

    return Optional
      .ofNullable(strings)
      .map(Stream::of)
      .map(stream -> stream.anyMatch(isBlank))
      .orElse(false);
  }

}
```

So, you can use this like `StringHelper.hasBlank("Hello", null, "", "  ")` or  `StringHelper.hasBlank("Hello")` in a generic form.

Comment: technically it is a good answer but performance wise may not be best

Comment: It looks like competition ))) Who can implement it longer!

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of below

```
Optional.ofNullable(result).filter(res -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(res))
            .ifPresent( s-> val.set(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

latest spring using hasText to validate a String as shown below

```
import org.springframework.util.StringUtil;
    
    class Test {
       public boolean isNullOrEmpty(String data) {
          return StringUtils.hasText(data);
       }
    }
```