# Simplify many if checks with Optional

Tags: java, if-statement, option-type

```
if (reg[0] != null && reg[0].trim().length() > 0) {
   orderData.setCity(reg[0]);
}
if (reg[1] != null && reg[1].trim().length() > 0) {
   orderData.setCountry(reg[1]);
}
if (reg[2] != null && reg[2].trim().length() > 0) {
   orderData.setObjectType(reg[2]);
}
if (reg[3] != null && reg[3].trim().length() > 0) {
   orderData.setChannel(reg[3]);
}
```

Can I simplify this with `Optional`, or other Java 8 features?

Comment: create a method that accepts a `String` and does that check for you, that would improve the readability a lot more.

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable(reg[0]).filter(r -> r.trim().length() > 0).ifPresent(orderData::setCity);` - Though I wouldn't say it's much cleaner.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32567208

Comment: Are the elements of the `reg` array all of type `String`?

Comment: yes, the reg array contains all String types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to really look for an implementation involving `Optional` here, the method I had suggested in comments could be implemented to return one

```
private Optional<String> validInput(String input) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(input)
                   .filter(in -> in.trim().length() > 0);
}
```

then this can be used as

```
validInput(reg[0]).ifPresent(city -> orderData.setCity(city));
validInput(reg[1]).ifPresent(country -> orderData.setCountry(country));
... and the likes
```

Comment: Hint: `city -> orderData.setCity(city)` can be shortened to `orderData::setCity`

Answer (score 3):

`Optional` would be the wrong tool here.

Leverage [`StringUtils.isNotBlank`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-) instead.

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(reg[0])) {
   orderData.setCity(reg[0]);
}
```

You still have to write each value out since they map to different fields, but this will clean it up and allow you to use a more conventional way to check for a blank string.

Comment: Naman's answer is a good example of how `Optional` can improve readability: `validInput(reg[0]).ifPresent(orderData::setCity)`. However, your answer better points out the actual issue he's having: he's wasn't abstracting out the validation into a re-usable form. Focusing on `Optional` is XY, but I wouldn't say it's a wrong tool for his situation, it's just not required to fix his problem, and kind of distracts from the actual issue he was having. Your answer makes it very clear that `Optional` isn't a requirement for solving this.

Answer (score 2):

Optional is probably not going to help you here.

The first thing to think of, is sentinel values. Here you are clearly indicating that you think that, semantically, `reg[0]` being null is equivalent to `reg[0]` being the empty string (or even a string with only spaces in it). That is supposed to be extraordinary. `null` is not a standin for 'nothing' or 'empty'. null is supposed to be a standin for 'There is no value'. The best way to do this, is to find the place that generates `reg[0]`, and ensure that the proper semantic meaning (an empty string) is set up here. Then this code can simply be: `if (!reg[0].isEmpty()) orderData.setCity(reg[0]);` - so much cleaner.

That is, of course, not always possible. For example, if `reg` is coming down the pipe from a library or other code that simply isn't under your control, or it is an object created by, say, a JSON demarshaller.

In that case I generally would advise creating an explicit step to convert an object that is 'not clean' (has nulls even when semantically that's supposed to be an empty string) into a clean one.

If that is not feasible or not possible, well, working with an 'unclean' object is never going to be particularly pretty, style wise. A helper method would help a lot, here:

```
normalizeThenSetIfNonBlank(reg[0], orderData::setCity);
normalizeThenSetIfNonBlank(reg[1], orderData::setCountry);

private void normalizeThenSetIfNonBlank(String in, Consumer<String> target) {
    if (in == null) return;
    in = in.trim();
    if (in.isEmpty()) return;
    target.accept(in);
}
```

Comment: This changes the semantics. OP's code processes untrimmed data; trimming was only for validation. Your code processes trimmed data. Although it may not matter, it's something to keep in mind. To keep the semantics the same, introduce a new local variable to reference the trimmed value, and validate on that instead of re-assigning the parameter variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Optional.ofNullable(reg[0]).filter(val -> val.trim().length() > 0).ifPresent(orderData::setCity);
Optional.ofNullable(reg[1]).filter(val -> val.trim().length() > 0).ifPresent(orderData::setCountry);
Optional.ofNullable(reg[2]).filter(val -> val.trim().length() > 0).ifPresent(orderData::setObjectType);
Optional.ofNullable(reg[3]).filter(val -> val.trim().length() > 0).ifPresent(orderData::setChannel);
```