# Empty check with parse int

Tags: java

A few days ago i posted a topic about `if/else` and `while loops`.
I have gotten a bit further and now made a little program to guess a number.

I would like to implement a feature to check if the user has an empty input but i cannot seem to figure it out!

Is there anyone who can help me a bit? Im still a pretty early beginner at **JAVA**.

**Here is my current code:**

```java
import  java.util.Scanner;
import  javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 * @author henluu
 */
public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create new scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int raad = 0;         
        raad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess the number"));

        while (Practice.rn() != raad) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, ("Your number is not the same as the random number"));
            raad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess the number"));
            //empty check
            if (raad == " ") {
                Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("No Input"));
            }
        }    
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, ("You guesse dit right! The number was: ") + Practice.rn());      
        }

    //method to generate random number
    public static int rn() {
        int random = (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        return random;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a bit strange. I've never heard of an empty number.  there is nothing like an empty number

Comment: Well, do some checks on the return of `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`, before the parsing. A String is empty if `isEmpty` return null. Of course, a String `"  "` is not empty. For the rest, well since your are a beginner, you should try it by yourself

Comment: You could start by reading [how to check a String](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3598770/4391450) value

Answer (score 0):

Since you are learning i'm not going show you the standard library solutions, but a solution that is library independant and allows you to grasp some logic points to check.
See the comments in the code below.

```
public boolean isNumeric(String input) {
    // First trim input of trailing spaces
    input = input.trim();

    // test on 0 length
    if(input.length == 0) {
       return false;
    }

    // Loop through all characters to test
    // if they are valid
    for(char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can then call it like this.

```
if(this.isNumeric(raad)) {
   // your code here
}
```

Further more, learn about the single responsiblity principle.

There are some serious flaws in your code. I'd suggest you post it also on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get some useful pointers where to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The point is: that JOptionPane is returning a **string** to you.

You could do something like:

```
private int fetchIntFromString(String userInput) {
  if (userInput.isEmpty()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("input must not be empty");
  }
  return Integer.parseInt(userInput);
}
```

to be used like:

```
try {
  raad = fetchIntFromString(JOptionPane.show...
} catch (Exception e) {
  ... give some error message
```

In other words: when the user gives a number, it is simply turned into a numeric value and returned. If the user input is empty or can't be parsed as number, an exception is thrown; which needs to be caught within the method that calls `fetchIntFromString()`