# Why null check is necessary in the below code?

Tags: java

```
public boolean isValidCardDetails(CardDetailsTypeBean cardDetailsTypeBean) throws EnrollmentReqInvalidException {
        if (cardDetailsTypeBean.getCardNumber() == null || "".equals(cardDetailsTypeBean.getCardNumber())) {
            throw new EnrollmentReqInvalidException("ECDOO16", "card no is mandatory");
        }
        if (cardDetailsTypeBean.getNameOnCard() == null || "".equals(cardDetailsTypeBean.getNameOnCard())) {
            throw new EnrollmentReqInvalidException("ECDOO17", "name on card is mandatory");
        }
        if (cardDetailsTypeBean.getCvv() == 0 || "".equals(String.valueOf(cardDetailsTypeBean.getCvv()))) {
            throw new EnrollmentReqInvalidException("ECDOO18", "cvv is mandatory");
        }
        if (cardDetailsTypeBean.getExpDate() == null || "".equals(cardDetailsTypeBean.getExpDate())) {
            throw new EnrollmentReqInvalidException("ECDOO19", "exp date must be required");
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Well here i want to ask after getting card number and checking null,why we use "".equals there..?? can anyone explain me this? little confused?

Comment: Cause you are dealing with String value. it could be null and also could be an empty string. isnt it sounds natural ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Comment: The conditions are checking for `null` first and then, if the object is initialized, they check for an empty `String`.

Comment: null means there is no instance of a object, it has not bean instantiated and does not have a values. With equals you check if the values is "" (empty), so that means that it is instantiated but its value is "" (empty).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether a string is not null and not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598770/check-whether-a-string-is-not-null-and-not-empty)

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
cardDetailsTypeBean.getCardNumber() == null || "".equals(cardDetailsTypeBean.getCardNumber())
```

simply verifies if `cardNumber` is `null` or if is equal to the empty string. Empty string is different from `null` value, so this code checks if every field read by a getter returns a non-empty, non-null value.

Comment: It's worth noting that because of the first condition, there is literally no benefit to the [Yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). It should be  `cardDetailsTypeBean.getCardNumber().equals("")`

Comment: Better to do the reverse: `"".equals(cardDetailsTypeBean.getCardNumber())` actually performs correctly the check with no need of doing any nullcheck.

Comment: Or maybe using Apache Commons `StringUtils.isEmpty`

Comment: It doesn't. `"".equals(null)` would return false, which would not cause a failure in OP's validation.

Answer (score 0):

It's superfluous, actually.

The reason for this is that the order of the `equals` statement on the other side of the logical comparison is *guaranteed* not to produce a `NullPointerException`, since `String.equals(null)` is engineered to produce `false`.

The reason it likely exists the way it does is that it's being made *explicit* that the code is checking for `null` *and* an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

`""` isn't the same as `null` because `""` is a `String` value. Your `card number` might instantiated with `""`

`null` means the reference of `card number` has no value.