# Program doesn't seem to be reading data from an array: NumberFormatException: empty String

Tags: java, file-io, numberformatexception

I'm working on a file reader that takes a file "PovertyData.txt", splits it into parts, and finds the percentage between two numbers. I want to write it to a binary file and then output it to another file using two main methods. However, when I run the first main method, I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
        at java.base/java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:461)
        at fileReader.toText(fileReader.java:151)
        at fileReader.splitFile(fileReader.java:128)
        at Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

The first class "Main" has the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {
        int lineCharCount = 130; //length of each line in file
        int outputCharCount = 28; //length of each output line
        String fileName = "PovertyData.txt"; //name of the imported file

        try (
            RandomAccessFile binDat = new RandomAccessFile("povertyBinary.dat", "rw");
            ) {
            File povertyFile = new File(fileName); //importing the file
            int [] includeData = {0, 1, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107}; //all the data values needed for the output
            int [] percentParameterOne = {100, 107}; //child poverty population character locations
            int [] percentParameterTwo = {91, 98}; //total child population character locations
            
            fileReader readFiles = new fileReader(lineCharCount, outputCharCount);
            readFiles.setIncludeData(includeData);
            readFiles.setPercentOne(percentParameterOne[0], percentParameterOne[1]);
            readFiles.setPercentTwo(percentParameterTwo[0], percentParameterTwo[1]);
            
            binDat.writeChars(readFiles.splitFile(povertyFile));
            }
        catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The class "fileReader" has the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fileReader {
    int lineCharCount; // number of spaces per line in the input
    int outputCharCount; // number of spaces the output will use
    int[] includeData; // data value places that will be included into the output
    String returnText = ""; // text that will be returned
    int[] percentDataOne = new int[2]; // the first set of data that will be the numerator of the percentage
    int[] percentDataTwo = new int[2]; // the second set of data that will be the denominator of the percentage

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public fileReader() {
        this.lineCharCount = 0;
        this.outputCharCount = 0;

        this.includeData = new int[outputCharCount];
        this.percentDataOne[0] = 0;
        this.percentDataOne[1] = 0;
        this.percentDataTwo[0] = 0;
        this.percentDataTwo[1] = 0;
        } // default constructor that sets everything to default values

    public fileReader(final int lineCharCount, final int outputCharCount) {
        this.lineCharCount = lineCharCount;
        this.outputCharCount = outputCharCount;

        this.includeData = new int[outputCharCount];
        } // constructor to set everything to custom values

    // SETTER METHODS
    public void setIncludeData(final int[] inputArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.includeData.length; i++) {
            this.includeData[i] = inputArray[i];
            }
        }

    public void setoutputCharCount(final int outputCharCount) {
        this.outputCharCount = outputCharCount;
        }

    public void setlineCharCount(final int lineCharCount) {
        this.lineCharCount = lineCharCount;
        }

    public void setPercentOne(int dataOne, int dataTwo) {
        this.percentDataOne[0] = dataOne;
        this.percentDataOne[1] = dataTwo;
        }
    
    public void setPercentTwo(int dataOne, int dataTwo) {
        this.percentDataTwo[0] = dataOne;
        this.percentDataTwo[1] = dataTwo;
        }

    // GETTER METHODS
    public int getlineCharCount() {
        return this.lineCharCount;
        }

    public int getoutputCharCount() {
        return this.outputCharCount;
        }

    public int[] getIncludeData() {
        return this.includeData;
        }

    // CUSTOM METHODS
    public String splitFile(final File file) throws IOException {
        int fileLength = 0;
        /* try (
            Scanner counter = new Scanner(new FileReader(file))
            ) {
            while (counter.hasNextLine()) {
                counter.nextLine();
                fileLength++;
                } //counts number of lines in the file
            } //automatically closes the scanner
        */ //Original code to count lines in the file (didn't work because it made the second scanner not scan anything and we got a NoSuchElementException)
        
        final ArrayList<String> allLines = (ArrayList<String>) Files.readAllLines(file.toPath()); // Makes an ArrayList "allLines" which finds the path of the file, locates the file, reads all the lines of the file "file" and copies them into individual array elements
        /*
         * Creates ArrayList of Strings (flexible array that I don't need to specify the
         * size/length of) Finds the path name of "file" Reads all the lines of "file"
         * Sets the ArrayList of Strings to be the same as every single line of "file"
         */

        fileLength = allLines.size(); // length (or size) of allLines should be the number of lines in the file

        final String[] inArray = new String[fileLength]; // array that will contain every line in the file
        
        allLines.toArray(inArray); //reads all contents of the ArrayList to the array

        String [] secArray = new String[this.lineCharCount]; // array that will contain every character of the line of inArray

        try (
            final Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < fileLength; i++) {
                inArray[i] = input.nextLine();
                } //puts all the lines of the file into a massive array
            } //automatically closes the scanner

        final String[][] outArray = new String[fileLength][this.lineCharCount]; // output array that will betranslated into text, has to be placed here for the .length attribute of inArray to be correct

        for (int h = 0; h < fileLength; h++) {
            //System.out.println("Reading..."); //debug
            secArray = inArray[h].split(""); //splits the line into portions
            
            for (int k = 0; k < this.lineCharCount; k++) {
                outArray[h][k] = secArray[k]; // h = # rows, k = # columns
                //System.out.println("Writing..."); //debug
                }
            } // nested loops to transfer information into the 2D array

        toText(outArray, fileLength, secArray);
        return this.returnText;
    } // massive method that splits a file into individual parts

    public void toText(final String[][] array, final int arrayLength, final String [] otherArray) {
        String percentStringOne = "";
        String percentStringTwo = "";
        float percentFloat;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            //System.out.println("Making Line"); //debug
            for (int j = 0; j < this.includeData.length; j++ ) {
                if (j > this.percentDataOne[0] && j < this.percentDataOne[1]) {
                    percentStringOne += otherArray[j];
                    } //an if statement that collects the number within the parameters defined in percentDataOne
                
                if (j > this.percentDataTwo[0] && j < this.percentDataTwo[1]) {
                    percentStringTwo += otherArray[j];
                    } //an if statement that collects the number within the parameters defined in percentDataTwo
                
                this.returnText += array[i] [this.includeData[j]];
                //System.out.println("Writing Data"); //debug 
                }
            percentFloat = Float.parseFloat(percentStringOne) / Float.parseFloat(percentStringTwo);
            this.returnText += " " + percentFloat + " \n";
            } //method turns the 2D array into a neat output
            //if includeData = {0, 2} and outArray = {{0, 2, 3}{8, 9, 14}} then returnText will equal to 0 3 \n 8 14
        } //method that converts the 2D array into readable text
    }
```

PovertyData.txt is over 10,000 lines long, here is an excerpt from it.

```
01 00190 Alabaster City School District                                              31754     6475      733 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00005 Albertville City School District                                            21522     4010     1563 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00030 Alexander City City School District                                         17292     2719     1158 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00060 Andalusia City School District                                               9044     1512      471 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00090 Anniston City School District                                               22759     3304     1122 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00100 Arab City School District                                                    8238     1491      250 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00120 Athens City School District                                                 23494     3767      770 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00180 Attalla City School District                                                 6019      971      283 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00210 Auburn City School District                                                 57441     7120      994 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00240 Autauga County School District                                              55246    10643     1855 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00270 Baldwin County School District                                             195540    32652     6171 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00300 Barbour County School District                                              14124     1769      759 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00330 Bessemer City School District                                               27510     4765     2009 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00360 Bibb County School District                                                 22512     3590     1096 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00390 Birmingham City School District                                            212631    30718    12740 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00420 Blount County School District                                               51246     9201     2218 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00012 Boaz City School District                                                    9619     1742      464 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00450 Brewton City School District                                                 5354      866      279 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00480 Bullock County School District                                              10639     1565      684 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014  
01 00510 Butler County School District                                               20265     3494     1430 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014
```

It appears that my attempts to read certain numbers doesn't work. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I see a lot of issues in the code. what are you trying to do?

Comment: If you're just trying to get that exception fixed, you will want to take your `percentFloat = Float.parseFloat(percentStringOne) / Float.parseFloat(percentStringTwo);` line from your `fileReader.toText` method and add checks to see if the `percentStringOne` and `percentStringTwo` [are not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598770/check-whether-a-string-is-not-null-and-not-empty) before trying to parse and return them.

Comment: @AnandVaidya I'm trying to take the PovertyData.txt file, write it to povertyBin.dat with an additional percentage statistic at the end based on the last two numbers.

Comment: @TimHunter It seems to be a cehcked exception, so I can't do that.