# How to check String in array is empty or null?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have code like as `String[] parts=str.split(":")` I want to confirm if parts[] array dont have any empty or null string. What is optimal way to do this ?

Comment: You won't have `null` element but you can have empty ones like if sentence if `Hey :: man :`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check whether a string is not null and not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598770/check-whether-a-string-is-not-null-and-not-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a `foreach` loop on the array

```
static boolean hasEmpty(String[] values){
    for(String elt : values)
        if(elt.isEmpty())
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

If you want to add a `not only whitespace string` use

```
if (elt.isEmpty() || elt.isBlank()) {
```