# How to find the selected id in my List<String> ids arraylist?

Tags: java, mysql, unit-testing, junit4, junit5

Here is my code. I am trying to use JUnit to test the deleteUsers() method, but everytime I write my test, it deletes all the users that I have in the database. How can i delete a single user? Below is the code for the method and for the test.

```
@Override
public boolean deleteUsers(List<String> ids) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("delete from user where ");
    for (String id : ids) {
        sql.append(" id = ? or");
    }
    String strSql = sql.toString().substring(0, sql.length() - 2) + ";";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.connection.prepareStatement(strSql);

    for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
        preparedStatement.setInt(1 + i, Integer.parseInt(ids.get(i)));
    }

    int lines = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    preparedStatement.close();
    return lines > 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you running these tests against a live database or have you implemented an in-memory db?

Comment: But your ddl statement is specifically designed to delete several users... So pass one id and get rid of `OR`

Comment: @TobyCook I am running these tests against a live database.

Comment: @g00se I am aware that my ddl statement is designed to delete several users, however i am having a problem passing a single id to the deleteUsers() method. If you don't mind showing me how to implement that according to your suggestion, I will highly appreciate it.

Comment: at no point in the test is the id of an existing user being added to the ids list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a check for empty input. In your test you pass an empty list to `deleteUsers` which results in this SQL statement:

```sql
delete from user wher;
```

I'd expect that the DBMS would reject this as invalid SQL but perhaps there are some where this is interpreted as `delete from user` which simply deletes all users. (As @SteveBosman pointed out the `wher` is interpreted as table alias as it is - due to the missing last `e` - no reserved word anymoere)

Basically you have 2 options. Either deleting all users by passing an empty list is a valid use case - in which case you should handle it properly by producing proper SQL. Or this is not expected and you should adapt your code to throw an Exception if `ids` is empty.

```
@Override
public boolean deleteUsers(List<String> ids) throws Exception {
  if (ids == null || ids.size() == 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("List of IDs must not be empty");
  }
  
  ...
}
```

You could of course return `false` in case of an empty input as well to indicate no users were deleted.

To pass values to the `deleteUsers` method in your test you need to add values to the used list:

```java
userDAOImpl.addUser("admin3", "111222");
final List<String> idsToDelete = new ArrayList<>();
idsToDelete.add("111222");
userDAOImpl.deleteUsers(idsToDelete);
```

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm blind and totally didn't see the substring that cuts of the last 2 characters of the string.

Comment: @dpr Thanks for your answer. This is helpful. However, when i try doing what you have suggested, it gives me the following error:

java.lang.AssertionError: expected null, but was:<[]>

Comment: Looks like your `findAllUsers` returns an empty list in case there are no users. I'd personally think this is correct. You should probably adapt the assertion and check for an empty list instead of `null`

Comment: The "wher" is treated as a table alias which is why it isn't being rejected.

Comment: @SteveBosman you're right of course. Good catch!

Comment: @dpr I appreciate your help last time. I have another problem with the same project, but this is on adding the users. How can i make sure that users with empty username and /or password should not be added to my database?

here is my implementation

```public boolean addUser(String userName, String password) throws Exception {
        //This is not working
        if(userName == null || password == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("username or password can't be empty");
        }

        String sql = "insert into user(username,password) values(?,?) ";```

Comment: @Sycan See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3598792

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by how the SQL is built. When deleteUsers is passed an empty list then the generated SQL will be:

```
 delete from user wher
```

which will result in all data being deleted (the table user is given the alias "wher"). I highly recommend checking at the start of the method if the collection is empty and either raising an exception or returning.

Add the following check

```
if (ids == null || ids.isEmpty()) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("ids must not be empty");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.append("delete from user where");
String orClause = "";
for (String id : ids) {
    sql.append(orClause);
    sql.append(" id = ?");
    orClause = " or";
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to append `;`. It's a single statement