# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in charAt() call

Tags: java, file, char, indexoutofboundsexception

I am new to coding and I am trying to make a program that matches two text files. For the first line, I match the first character and the second line I match two characters and so on until one of the files ends.

Here is the problem. If the line does not have enough characters you only compare what is present, if both lines 99 have `"abc"` then it would be considered a match.

I can't seem to fulfill this requirement without it throwing an error because `charAt()` is reading a null if the number of characters is less than the number of lines. Thanks for the help!

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    boolean flag;
    File f = new File(args[0]);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    File f2 = new File(args[1]);
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(f2);
    int line = 1;
    String t1 = "";
    String t2 = "";
    String work = "";

    while(sc.hasNext() && sc2.hasNext())
    {
        String line1 = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        String line2 = sc2.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        line1 = line1.trim();
        line2 = line2.trim();
        for(int i = 0; i < line; i++)
        {
            if(line1.charAt(i) != line2.charAt(i))
            {
                work = "no";
                t1 = Character.toString(line1.charAt(i));
                t2 = Character.toString(line2.charAt(i));
            }
            else
            {
                work = "";
                t1 = Character.toString(line1.charAt(i));
                t2 = Character.toString(line2.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        if(work == "")
        {
            System.out.println("Line # " + line + ": Matching " + line + " character/s true " + "**" + line1 + "**" + " and " + "**" + line1 + "**");

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Line # " + line + ": Matching " + line + " character/s false " + "**" + line1 + "**" + " and " + "**" + line2 + "**");
        }
        line += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont `if(line1.charAt(i) != line2.charAt(i))` , use `if(line1.charAt(i).equals(line2.charAt(i)))`

Comment: [`use equals() to compare`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). @Sekula1991 It primitive types.so `==` is fine

Comment: You gotta check if the result of charAt() is null, then handle accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the length of your line1 and line2 versus your i variable before you call char at past the end of the last letter of the line.

Something like if(line1.length() < i)

[String.length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length())

Answer (score 0):

1st check if both lines are of equal length as follows (and change variable `work` as `boolean` instead of `String`). It helps with performance since `boolean` takes 1 byte and `String` more than that.

```
if (line1.length() > line2.length()) {
    work = false;
} else if (line1.length() < line2.length()) {
    work = false;
} else if (line1.charAt(i) != line2.charAt(i)) {
    work = false;
} else {
    work = true;
}
```

Or:

```
if (line1.length() != line2.length()) {
    work = false;
} else {
    work = true;
}
```

Or:

```
if (line1.length() == line2.length()) {
    work = true;
} else {
    work = false;
}
```

Then

```
if(work) {//This is the same as if (work == true)
    System.out.println("Line # " + line + ": Matching " + line + " character/s true " + "**" + line1 + "**" + " and " + "**" + line1 + "**");
} else {
    System.out.println("Line # " + line + ": Matching " + line + " character/s false " + "**" + line1 + "**" + " and " + "**" + line2 + "**");
}
```

But if you really really want / need to use `work` variable as `String` then don't compare it with `==` but `work.equals("")` or `"".equals(work)` (the second one prevents `NullPointerException`.

Read more about [`.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)), [Java == vs equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) and [How do I compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). And about [`"".equals(variable)` vs `variable.equals("")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531779/comparing-a-string-with-the-empty-string-java/531825#531825)

Also you might want to `break` or `continue` your loop if at any position the 2 lines don't match at any letter.