# i try to avoid saving empty records in data base with this code but it also save empty records

Tags: android

```
saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            questionStr = String.valueOf(questionET.getText());
            answerOneStr = String.valueOf(ansOneET.getText());
            answerTwoStr = String.valueOf(ansTwoET.getText());
            answerThreeStr = String.valueOf(ansThreeET.getText());
            answerFourStr = String.valueOf(ansFourET.getText());
            correctAnswerStr = String.valueOf(correctAnsET.getText());
            if (questionStr == null || answerOneStr == null || answerTwoStr == null || correctAnswerStr == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Fill Fields ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                questionManagerObject.InsertIntoQuestions(questionStr, answerOneStr, answerTwoStr, answerThreeStr, answerFourStr, correctAnswerStr, questionTableSubjectId);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Question Saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

this is the save button code ...i tried to change null to empty "" but there is no changes

Comment: Perhaps this will shed some light? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531779/comparing-a-string-with-the-empty-string-java

Comment: android sdk provides `TextUtils`: It has `isEmpty()` method. It is simple String null checker. try this `TextUtils.isEmpty(questionStr)` at `if` statements.

Comment: no , it does not help , if the user enter one space it will be saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method:

```
private boolean isEmpty(String str)
{
    if (str == null || str.trim().isEmpty())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

then use it in your code:

```
if (isEmpty(questionStr) || isEmpty(answerOneStr) ||  
    isEmpty(answerTwoStr) || isEmpty(answerThreeStr) || 
    isEmpty(answerFourStr) ||isEmpty(correctAnswerStr))
{
   // your code
}
```

Comment: thank you very very very much  , your answer helped me

Comment: I would use the standard function instead: `TextUtils.isEmpty()`. See [doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)). The input string should be trimmed though.

Answer (score 0):

Use String.trim() to make sure it's not a space then move on to your conditional.

[trim whitespace from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796121/trim-whitespace-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your empty checking by this:

```
 if (questionStr == null && answerOneStr == null 
             && answerTwoStr == null && correctAnswerStr == null) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Fill Fields ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```