# When I update with SQL, if a field is empty, it changes that value empty in the database

Tags: mysql, java

I have a table with 6 columns: userid, firstname, lastname, title, squad, and email. When I want to update ONLY one of these, I will only input text into the respective text field. For instance, if I want to update firstname, I am only going to write the new firstname and I won't put anything for lastname, title, etc.

The problem is that when I don't put anything for those other text fields, the database assumes that I wanted to update those values to empty and when I run the database, there's nothing there anymore. How do I fix this?

```java
String ID = textID.getText();
String first = textFirstName.getText();
String last = textLastName.getText();
String title = textTitle.getText();
String squad = textSquad.getText();
String email = textEmail.getText();

int newID = Integer.parseInt(ID);
int newSquad = Integer.parseInt(squad);

try {  
    if(first != null) {
        String sql = "Update colleagues " + "set firstname = ? " + "where userid = ?";
        PreparedStatement upd = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

        upd.setString(1, first); // replace first ? with value for first name
        upd.setInt(2, newID);    // replace second ? with value for userid
        upd.executeUpdate();    
    }

    if(last != null) {
        String sql = "Update colleagues " + "set lastname = ? " + "where userid = ?";
        PreparedStatement upd = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

        upd.setString(1, last); 
        upd.setInt(2, newID);    
        upd.executeUpdate();
    }
// ...
```

Comment: @joanolo I have decided to use `first.length() > 0` but I'm getting this error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: I guess this happens somewhere else... where an *integer* is expected you're passing an empty string. Step through your code and find out.

Comment: @joanolo it works now! I can't seem to find the checkmark to indicate that this question has been answered. All I see is a star

Comment: I've posted it as an answer, and some comments about the fact that this is no longer a database question, and should better be moved to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of comparing

```
(first != null)
```

which compares the value of `first` to the null value (which, I guess, is never returned by the `getText()` function) you should compare

```
(!("".equals(first))
```

See [Comparing a string with the empty string (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531779/comparing-a-string-with-the-empty-string-java)

---

BTW: This is not any longer a question about databases, but about Java Programming. It would be best answered in stackoverflow than in DBA.SE

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle such checks, is to use a tested, open source and production ready library you can fully trust like [apache common-lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html).
There is plenty of utils classes that you can use for those 'simple' tasks so you don't have to rewrite them yourself.